# How to allow page-breaks in columns/list

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, context

I've got a following fragment to display in two columns:

```
Some heading    Some longer
                description
                  * with
                  * a
                  * list
```

I'm using the following def:

```
\def\DataPair#1#2{%
   \defineparagraphs[TwoColumns][n=2]%
   \setupparagraphs[TwoColumns][1][width=\LeftColumnWidth,align=left]%
   \startTwoColumns%
      {\tfx{\sc #1}}%
   \TwoColumns%
      {#2}%
   \stopTwoColumns%
}
```

Where the content is:

```
Some longer description
\startitemize[packed]
   \item with
   \item a
   \item list
\stopitemize
```

Unfortunately the that block ignores page breaking. Is there some way I can allow `\DataPair` to page-break at any point?

Comment: Try to make a running simple example. The problem here has nothing to do with itemize. The problem here is that text inside defined paragraphs is not broken to the next page. MWE: `\defineparagraphs[Two][n=1]
\starttext
\startTwo\dorecurse{6}{\input knuth}\stopTwo
\stoptext`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `tabulate`?

```
\starttext                                                                                     
\starttabulate[|l|p|]
  \NC Some Heading \NC 
      Some longer description
      \input knuth
      \startitemize
          \dorecurse{60}{\item Item \recurselevel}
      \stopitemize
  \NC \NR
\stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

You can wrap it around a macro as:

```
\define[2]\DataPair
  {\starttabulate[|l|p|]
      \NC #1 \NC #2 \NC \NR
   \stoptabulate}
```