# Context: xtable row over multiple pages

Tags: context, extreme-tables

For layout reasons I would like to embed my data into a table. Now I'm having a problem if a row is really large because the page is overflowing.

How can I allow a page break if this happens?

MWE:

```
\starttext
\startxtable[option={stretch,width},split=yes]
  \startxrow[foregroundcolor=white,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]
  \startxcell[nx=2]  \bf Table NAME\stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow
    \startxcell[width=0.5cm,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]\stopxcell
    \startxcell[background=color, backgroundcolor=gray] \bf Description: \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow
    \startxcell[width=0.5cm,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]\stopxcell
    \startxcell 
      \startitemize
        \dorecurse{60}{\item Item \recurselevel}
    \stopitemize
    \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

Comment: Are you tied to `xtable`? I don't know much about `xtable` but a previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446864/how-to-create-tables-that-spill-into-the-next-page-in-context) with regard to natural tables was redirected to use `tabulate` as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50667/141419

Comment: That only works with `tabulate`, see the linked duplicate for an example.

Comment: There is actually an issue with tabulate and cell background colors.  I have started a thread on the mailing list: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/092564.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hackish variant with Extreme Tables would be to put every item in its own row.

```
\starttext
\startxtable[option={stretch,width},split=yes]
  \startxrow[foregroundcolor=white,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]
  \startxcell[nx=2]  \bf Table NAME\stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \startxrow
    \startxcell[width=0.5cm,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]\stopxcell
    \startxcell[background=color, backgroundcolor=gray] \bf Description: \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \dorecurse{60}{%
    \startxrow[topframe=off,bottomframe={\ifnum\recurselevel=60 on\else off\fi}]
      \startxcell[width=0.5cm,background=color,backgroundcolor=black]\stopxcell
      \startxcell 
        \startitemize
        \item Item \recurselevel
        \stopitemize
      \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  }
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

[image]

You might also want to use the short syntax and some setups to compact your code.

```
\setupxtable
  [whiteonblack]
  [foregroundcolor=white,
   foregroundstyle=bold,
   background=color,
   backgroundcolor=black]

\setupxtable
  [blackongray]
  [foregroundcolor=black,
   foregroundstyle=bold,
   background=color,
   backgroundcolor=gray]

\starttext
\startxtable[option={stretch,width},split=yes]
  \NC[whiteonblack][nx=2] Table NAME \NR
  \NC[whiteonblack][width=0.5cm] \NC[blackongray] Description: \NR
  \dorecurse{60}{%
    \NC[whiteonblack][width=0.5cm]
    \NC[topframe=off,bottomframe={\ifnum\recurselevel=60 on\else off\fi}]
      \startitemize
      \item Item \recurselevel
      \stopitemize
    \NR
  }
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

Comment: That looks promising. Is there a way to add frames at the page break? With that I mean add the bottomframe to the last cell of the first page and add the topframe to the first cell on the secon page?

Comment: @christopher2505 When you know which of the rows end up at the pagebreak, you can add them to the conditional.